# Angular - attribute can be read in dev mode but not in prod mode

Tags: angular, attributes, angular-directive

I am using Angular version 6.0.8

I have an `autoid` directive that reads the name attribute and sets an id attribute to the element that it is applied to.
Here is the code that reads the name attribute

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    let nameAttribute = this.elRef.nativeElement.attributes["name"];

    if (!nameAttribute) {
        console.error("value of name attribute is not set", this.elRef.nativeElement);
    }
}
```

Here is a sample usage:

```
<myapp-dimension-select [(ngModel)]="model.ParentDepartmentId"
                       name="parent"
                       autoid>
</myapp-dimension-select>
```

This code works fine in dev mode, but the error is reported when I build with `--prod`.

I am unable to find what might be causing the issue.

Comment: Which error is reported? Can you show the error message please?

Comment: @PhilippKief: I mean the error message that I have written if `nameAttribute` is not defined.